# Start video on a second monitor?

Tags: windows, delphi, vlc

I like to run one video at monitor 1 and with delay of a second another video on monitor 2.

I decided to use VLC player for this task and that's quite a hassle.

```
C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC "&& vlc --fullscreen --video-on-top --no-video-title-show --mouse-hide-timeout=0 --high-priority D:\1.avi --directx-device=\\.\DISPLAY1

C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC "&& vlc --fullscreen --video-on-top --no-video-title-show --mouse-hide-timeout=0 --high-priority D:\2.avi --directx-device=\\.\DISPLAY2
```

It does not matter what team I would not use the video runs on the screen on which I ran and shut the player.

How can I fix this?

Alternatively, can I do this by hosting two VLC viewer windows within my Delphi application and if so, how?

Comment: Your q originally mentioned Delphi.  Are you trying to write an application which runs locally on a PC and uses two monitors  or which display the videos in a web page?

Comment: Sorry for the google translation)

Thank you for your interest.
Yes I do the program on Delphi, it works locally, to which two monitors are connected.

That image of the structure.  http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1460048781/6711b441/12196878.png

Comment: As written this is not a programming question. If the language is a problem, delete this, and as on the Russian site.

Comment: Sorry, SO is an English-language site.  You know you can use the VLC ActiveX in a Delphi app?  To do that you import C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll as a Type Library.

Comment: Thanks to this excellent advice, unfortunately Russian community is not able to help me.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/193342

Comment: There's a Russian stack overflow site!

Comment: @MartynA adding the Delphi tag doesn't make it a programming question. Please don't add the tag and answer without fixing the Q too. Think about future readers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan;  Well, ordinarily I do not like putting words in other people's mouths, but as the OP seems satisfied with my answer, I've taken the liberty of editing the q's text to frame the q I understood him to be asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not quite clear exactly what your question is, but perhaps this will help.

As I mentioned in a comment, you can import the VLC ActiveX into Delphi, if you have not already done so, and use that to embed the VLC player window in a form of your project.  There are a few minor problems with it, and it takes a bit of learning, but is fairly straightforward.  There are quite a few useful answers on SO about the details of using it.

And, of course, you can use a second monitor in a Delphi app.

Unlike Windows Media player, VLC seems happy to be run as multiple instances at the same time.  I've never tried using two VLC ActiveXs in the same Delphi app but can't immediately see why it would not work. You can control most aspects of the play operation in the ActiveX, including speed, starting time, auto-loop, etc.